ffmpeg problem video duration of an hour and a half
When start record i call an api /start-record which does:
const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
        "-i",
        rtsp,
        "-c:v",
        "copy",
        "-an",
        "-f",
        "flv",
        `${filename}.flv`,
      ]);
ffmpegProcesses[rtsp] = {
        process: ffmpeg,
        filename,
      };

When stop the record i call an api /stop-record which does:
ffmpegProcesses[rtsp].process.kill("SIGKILL");
ffmpegProcesses[rtsp].process.on("exit", async () => {
   const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
          "-i",
          `${filename}.flv`,
          "-c:v",
          "libx264",
          "-preset",
          "fast",
          "-crf",
          "30",
          "-an",
          `${filename}.mp4`,
        ]);

    ffmpeg.on("exit", async () => {
        uploadToS3()
    })

})

If the recording is less than or equal to approximately 1 hour it works perfectly, but if the recording is 1 and a half hours it already breaks and it does not correctly generate the files, nor the flv nor the conversion to mp4
I hope my program works the same way it does for 1 hour recordings

what is being corrupted? did you run a mediainfo? is the file not working before or after upload to s3?

There are times when the file is never finished converting to mp4 and other times where the recording is cut off much earlier, for example at minute 20.

what debugging have you done? did you examine ffmpeg logs? are there relevant any logs for node itself? have you checked for network issues?
